# on click event fires only once rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

This is my code included in `custom.js`

```
//on turbolinks load
var ready;

ready = function() {
    console.log("turbolinks ready")
    $("body").on("click", ".show-answer-link",function(){
        alert(1)
    });
};

//on documentload and on turbolinks load call ready function (it is calling just once)
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

also I have

```
<a class="show-answer-link>show</a>
```

And the click event fires only once.

If I move js script from external file to inline 
`<script>` tag - it works very well.

In case you need it - my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_custom
//= require_tree .
```

And also in my Gemfile I have

```
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change order of `require ..`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require_custom
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
return false;
```

to my click function solved the issue!